# Android Whatsapp constantly notifying about web login

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

I tried Whatsapp web using chrome browser in Windows and it works great. But, I don't like my android app notifying often that 'there was an active web login'. I am using Samsung A7 and my other friend uses Oneplus. He says he don't get any notifications regarding whatsapp web. I believe it could be a settings issue but not able to figure it. Any idea?

We both are using Oreo.

Note: I am new to Android ecosystem

Answer (score 0):

Android does give you the ability to configure the notifications you receive,

There is a nice guide on the whatsApp FAQ section of their website https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000003/.

**Summary:**
There are 2 areas that you can alter notification settings
1. Navigate to your phone's Settings app > Apps & notifications > WhatsApp > App notifications. Adjust settings here to your desired requirements.

2. Open WhatsApp > tap More options  > Settings > Notifications. Here you can set notifications for messages, groups, and calls